# mysql search where clause with each condition having different score

Tags: mysql, performance, search

**In Sum**

I have two columns, name and name_searchable. I'd like to search in these columns (which have millions of rows) and return the results in accordance with their match rate. I have two important criteria; the search should be efficient and fast. How can I achieve this?

**In Details**

I am planning to have a table with millions of rows. So basically, I created a dump table just to test the query with a million rows. The table is using the `MyISAM` storage engine, it's index and primary key is the id number. The search I'd like to make is concerned with the name field which is a `varchar` column. Now, based on a query, I'd like to return all results that match partly or in whole with the query. So when a user searches for 'björn borg' I'd like to return both:

- björn borg
- björn borgus
- bjorn borg (notice the o)

and so on...

The important factor here is that the `=` operator should always return higher ranked than the `LIKE` operator. Therefore, 'björn borg' should always come before 'bjorn borgus'.

Lately, I asked the question on how to return results in diacritics insensitive mode, but unfortunately I could not make it work. Therefore, I've created another column along the name column which stores the name in only English characters. So we have the `name` and `name_searchable` field.

Well, I tried the whole thing with a stored procedure,  but apparently it's really slow when compared to normal queries. Therefore, I'd like know whether I can order the results in accordance with which where clause they match. In other words:

```
SELECT * FROM myUsers WHERE name = 'björn borg' OR name_searchable = 'bjorn borg' OR name LIKE '%björn borg%' OR name_searchable LIKE '%bjorn borg%';
```

So basically, the idea is to give a score point to each condition differently. I mean, while name = 'björn borg' should have the rank, say, 5, name_searchable LIKE '%bjorn borg%' should have 2 (and the second one 4 points, the third one 3 points...) How can I make this work using MySql? (Efficiency and Speed are important factors to me)

Comment: You'd probably be better off running multiple independent queries, rather than trying to do this in one. where clauses are NOT a good place to be doing calculations of this sort.

Answer (score 1):

You will get much better performance if you don't do `LIKE '%<text>%'` because this will not use the index correctly, instead you should use `LIKE '<text>%'`. I would suggest you consider if you want users to be able to search for `name_searchable LIKE '%s%'` and the associated performance hit when the query takes a very long time and returns far too many results.

Have you tried

```
SELECT CASE WHEN name = 'björn borg' THEN 1 
  WHEN name_searchable = 'bjorn borg' THEN 2 
  WHEN name LIKE '%björn borg%' THEN 3 
  WHEN name_searchable LIKE '%bjorn borg%' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END AS rank, * 
FROM myUsers 
WHERE name = 'björn borg' 
  OR name_searchable = 'bjorn borg' 
  OR name LIKE '%björn borg%' 
  OR name_searchable LIKE '%bjorn borg%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'björn borg' THEN 1 
  WHEN name_searchable = 'bjorn borg' THEN 2 
  WHEN name LIKE '%björn borg%' THEN 3 
  WHEN name_searchable LIKE '%bjorn borg%' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END
```

Of course the fastest way to do this would be to add a `LIMIT 1`

Another option is to only use the like searches when the exact matches fail:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN name = 'björn borg' THEN 1 
  WHEN name_searchable = 'bjorn borg' THEN 2 
  WHEN name LIKE '%björn borg%' THEN 3 
  WHEN name_searchable LIKE '%bjorn borg%' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END AS rank, * 
FROM myUsers 
WHERE name = 'björn borg' 
  OR name_searchable = 'bjorn borg' 
  OR (
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM myUsers WHERE name = 'björn borg' OR name_searchable = 'bjorn borg' )
    AND (
    OR name LIKE '%björn borg%' 
    OR name_searchable LIKE '%bjorn borg%'
    )
  )
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'björn borg' THEN 1 
  WHEN name_searchable = 'bjorn borg' THEN 2 
  WHEN name LIKE '%björn borg%' THEN 3 
  WHEN name_searchable LIKE '%bjorn borg%' THEN 4 ELSE 5 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered separating the queries and `UNION`ing them?

```
SELECT 5 AS rank, * FROM myUsers WHERE name = 'björn borg' UNION
SELECT 4 AS rank, * FROM myUsers WHERE name_searchable = 'bjorn borg' UNION
SELECT 3 AS rank, * FROM myUsers WHERE name LIKE '%björn borg%' UNION
SELECT 2 AS rank, * FROM myUsers WHERE name_searchable LIKE '%bjorn borg%'
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, wouldn't this mean to search the whole table 4 times? In other words for a 10m records, it's like searching 40m records. Or does mysql cache the first select statement and things process much faster?

Comment: It is not like searching 40m records, because the indexes on this table would be substantially larger if your table had 40m records in it. I'm not an expert on the internals of MySQL. They are probably executed as separate queries, but the relevant data will probably be kept in memory until all the queries finish.